# Ubuntu 11.10 login screen acting strange after installing alongside windows

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, gnome3

I had Ubuntu 11.10 on my Dell laptop with GNOME 3 installed and everything worked like a charm.

I backed up my users' home folders, installed windows and then Ubuntu and GNOME 3 for a dual boot. After restoring my home folder from backup, I discovered that GRUB loads with an old Debian background and very small text. This is a non-issue, but I brought it up because I think it might be relevant to my other problem. Instead of the new Ubuntu login screen, which I had before, I have the GNOME 2 login screen without a user list. I can't seem to find any preferences dialog for the login screen like GNOME used to have either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this 
[Restore Ubuntu Lightdm](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74196/how-to-restore-lightdm-settings)
now i am not sure if that is the login software you are using but it is the default
for the new ubuntu.

Comment: It seemed to be the login software I was using since it was the only display manager there.

Comment: Correction, I did have gdm. I switched to lightdm, which gave me the login screen I expected but caused a new problem. GRUB now flashes on the screen for less than a second which doesn't give me the time to select the OS I want.

Comment: so you are still stuck?

Comment: Nope, I got it. Somehow a line got deleted from grubs conf file so I just pasted in a standard file I got off somebody's blog.